# Is it possible to rope pictures in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2010

I know I can always click on them one at a time, but that is very time consuming.  I can rope select many cells at a time, but if there are pictures in the spreadsheet, it will ignore the pictures.  Is there any way to change the selection mode in Excel so that picture can be selected via the rope method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On the Home Tab, go to Find and Select, Select Objects, your cross pointer becomes an arrow and you can now rope select.

Repeat the steps to get back to your normal pointer (it will get majorly confusing for most users since you cannot select cells anymore).

Comment: +1 because I learned a new thing today. :)  The `select objects` option in Word is in a similar spot, but it has its own visible button there.  I was totally missing it within the "binoculars" button in Excel.

Answer (score 6):

Don't know about a rope method but this works

- Select worksheet
- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>
- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- Type this and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

  ```
  Activesheet.pictures.Select
  ```
- If you just want to select one, replace the above line with

  ```
  Activecell.pictures.Select
  ```

Or you could add Select Multiple Objects to your Drawing Toolbar (click the little arrow at the end of the toolbar and use Add/Remove button).

Comment: That immediate window trick may have just changed how I use Excel forever.

Comment: I usually use it to offset complicated selections rather than reselect

Answer (score 4):

I'm not aware of a way to "rope select" in Excel, but there is a tool in Excel for selecting multiple images quickly.  Start by selecting one image so you gain access to the **Picture Tools** section of the task ribbon.  On the **Format** tab, in the **Arrange** section, click on **Selection Pane**.  This will open a **Selection and Visibility** pane, typically on the right of the window, with all the images from your workbook shown in a list.  From here you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> to select multiple images quickly, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select them all at once.

P.S. PowerPoint has the same tool.